# Blazor WASM (.NET Core Hosted) - Web API - Bad Request 404 for Complex Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Good day everyone

I have created a Blazor Web Assembly with.NET Core Hosted, I create 2 models one is the transaction details and one is the transaction Item details

Transactions:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TransactionNo { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [ListNullValidation(ErrorMessage = "Please fill up the transaction items")]
    public ICollection<TranasctionItems>? transactionItems { get; set; }
}
```

And Transaction Items

```
public class TranasctionItems
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

The I created a Web API that will add the new transactions

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddTransaction")]
public ActionResult<Transaction> AddTransaction([FromBody] Transaction transaction)
{
    try
    {
        _tranactions.InsertTransaction(transaction);
        return Ok(transaction);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Problem(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

then when I called the web API, I got the error "Bad Request 400", so I'm stock on this error, then I enable the swagger and found out that the transaction item is null, but upon checking, the transaction item was not, but web API does not recognize the ICollection, so what I did is I remove the custom validation and it work's but still it did not save the transaction items, so what I have to create another API for the transaction item.

so the question is, is this the behavior of web API, in which I cannot use an object that has a collection object, if not, then did I miss something? please help me on this.

THanks you

Comment: please show what the _transactions object is and what is the InsertTransaction